# How do I finish this loop? Concatenate two previous characters

Tags: javascript

I'm making a function that when you give it a string, it will return the uppercase of the even numbered chars and the lower case of the odd numbered ones. So if you give it "HELLO" it will give you "HeLlO". This is obviously wrong since it only works for the first two characters. How do I complete the loop so that it doesn't keep concatenating the strings together?

```
function evenOddChange(source)
{
    var i;
    var result;
    i = 0;
    result = "";
    while ( i < (source.length))
    {
        result = result + source.toUpperCase().charAt(i) + source.toLowerCase().charAt(i + 1);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you actually want the program to do?

Comment: The function is passed a string(source). It will basically change all the even numbered characters of the string to UpperCase and lowerCase for the odd numbered characters. For example evenOddChange("Right"), would return "RiGhT".

Comment: Then, why don't you check the current index and if it is odd change the current character to upper case and lower case otherwise?

Comment: @thefourtheye Actually the OP's algorithm does work with a small change. That being said I'm not saying that is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment by 2, not 1:

```
i = i + 2;
```

Not you are changing `i` and `i+1`, incrementing by only one will overwrite the `i+1` change. This simple change will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use`modulo` to check if its `even` or `Odd`.

```
function evenOddChange(source)
{
    var i;
    var result;
    i = 0;
    result = "";
    while ( i < (source.length))
    { 
        if(i%2==0){
           result = result + source.toUpperCase().charAt(i);
        }else{
           result = result + source.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        }

        i = i + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use modulus to find if the index is odd or even and then use bracket notation.

```
function evenOddChange(source) {
    var i = 0, result = "";
    while (i < source.length)
       result += source[i][i++ % 2 == 0 ? "toUpperCase" : "toLowerCase"]();
    return result;
}
```

Note that when we are doing `i++ % 2`, the modulus operator operates on the value of `i` *before* we increment it. The increment effect will be felt only in the next iteration.